# how can I use assembler in monotouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using monotouch, and I wanna do a simple arithmetic operation. But i havent find the way to do it in mono.

how can I multiply an int and a float in assembler in monotouch? I know that this is posible in iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice: measure before optimize. Early optimization is evil™.

That being said, you can simply code your assembly code and expose it to Objective-C as you would usually do ([this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/37181/ios-assembly-tutorial) and [this](http://www.shervinemami.info/armAssembly.html) are good references if you need more info) and then add a C# binding to your brand new Obj-C library (more about obj-c to c# binding topic in [this article](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c))

Cheers!